# RestKit. How to make post with query params?

Tags: ios, swift, request, restkit

I'm trying to use RestKit in my project.

Here is a code:

```
        let temporaryUrl = String(baseURL: urlPath, parameters: parameters)

        let request = RKObjectManager.sharedManager().requestWithObject(nil, method: method, path: temprorarryUrl, parameters: [:])

        let responseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: mapping, method: method, pathPattern: urlPath, keyPath: temprorarryUrl, statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(.Successful))

        let operation = RKObjectRequestOperation(request: request, responseDescriptors: [responseDescriptor])
```

But I'm always getting an error: ***"No response descriptors match the response loaded."***

I know that it is because my parameters is in query and must be in body. But for now I should manage it in this way.

Maybe there is some way to dill with it? (give some another pathPatter or something else).

Example of variables:

- urlPath: String = "user/sign_up"
- Parameters: [String : String] = ["email" : "foo@goo.boo"]
- TemporaryUrl: String = "user/sign_up?email=foo@goo.boo"
- Method: RKRequestMethod = .POST

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give details of the request and the descriptor path pattern you expect to match. turn on trace logging to check what's considered

Comment: @Wain updated my question

Comment: that should still match as the query parameters aren't considered in the pattern matching IIRC